# migration from normal chat to ejabberd chat

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd

I have been using the normal javascript ajax chat i created manually. I also used this same format to create phone android messenger app. But it was using normal sockets. 
so i have migrated to using ejabberd IM server and have developed the xmpp client messenger and it is working well with mysql module configurations.
But now i have history chats for messages by users and want to maintain the message. So i want to transfer these messages to the new database table called archive under ejabberd.
I have failed import the messages as they are very many in thousands.
so if some one know a script i can use to do the migration of data to the new database that will be good.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is not template migration script you can adapt already, but that would make a good contribution for ejabberd.